# In Matlab, how do I capture as output the mean of a particular column of a subset of an array without creating any new variables?

Tags: matlab

So I want to find the mean of the third column of this array without having to create an entirely new variable.

I can try `mean(seals(seals(:,3,1) < 10,:,1))`, which outputs a `1X5` vector. But is there a way to capture the 3rd column of the `1X5` vector without having to create an entirely new variable?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand what you want correctly, the following code should do the job

```
mean(seals(seals(:,3,1) < 10,3,1))
```

There is nothing wrong with creating a new variable in my opinion. The above code is not that readable...